# Always have to set Target Membership for .a File

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode7, .a

I am using `Flyer` and `Crittercism` in my project . both have `libAppsFlyerLib.a` and `libCrittercism_v4_3_4.a` respectively.

[image]

Now whenever I open my project and run it I always got this error first time.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>
> '-LApp/Model/Utility/CrittercismSDK' ld: warning: directory not found
>
> for option '-LApp/Model/CrittercismSDK' ld: warning: directory not
>
> found for option '-LApp' ld: warning: directory not found for option
>
> '-LApp/Model/Flyer' ld: warning: directory not found for option
>
> '-FApp/Model/Fabric' ld: library not found for -lAppsFlyerLib clang:
>
> error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

To resolve this I have to uncheck and again check Target Membership to Project for both `libAppsFlyerLib.a` and `libCrittercism_v4_3_4.a` manually.After that project is running fine.

[image]

Why I have to always set membership for `.a` file manually first time? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are those warnings relating to the `-L` and `-F` flags correct?

Comment: @trojanfoe frankly speaking I dont have idea about -L and -F

Comment: Well they are used to tell the linker where to find libraries and frameworks and are the likely culprit in this case.   You need to check your project settings,

Comment: ohk thanks @trojanfoe for your suggestion I will check that and let you know.

Comment: App/Model/Utility/CrittercismSDK this is old path I changed it to App/Model/CrittercismSDK . is that causing issue ? @trojanfoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `@trojanfoe`'s suggestion I get right direction to solve this issue and found that it is happening because it has no `library search path` in **build->setting** . So I set path to both `.a` in `library search path` file and it works.